# Editing and updating sqlite3 views with Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

We are accessing our sqlite3 database through `Flask` and `sqlalchemy`. So far we can **access**, **display** and **edit** the database's tables having modified `models.py` and `views.py` according to our requirements.

Next we have managed to retrieve the sqlite3 database's `views` *(not to be confused to the views in the `views.py` file of `sqlalchemy`)*.

However, we are getting the following error when trying to **edit** the fields through our `flask-app`.

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (sqlite3.OperationalError) cannot modify my_view because it is a view [SQL: 'UPDATE my_view SET "my_field"=?, WHERE my_view.id = ?'] [parameters: ('my_view_data')] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)`

It seems this error could be due to various reasons:

1) Either we need to implement a `session.no_autoflush` block as suggested in the error?

2) Or this is `Flask` limitation where sqlite3 database `views` cannot be handled by `Flask`? In which case we would have to abandon our database `views` and focus on our `tables` while rebuilding `views` from within `Flask` to obtain the same result?

We have tried to research but have found little information relating to `Flask` and `Sqlite3 views`.

Some pointers to set us in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html): *You cannot DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE a view. Views are read-only in SQLite.* Do not confuse SQLite without DBMS's which may allow updateable views.

Comment: Noted, but this is odd since when I am in SQLiteStudio I can update a field in view which updates the corresponding field in the mapped table.

Comment: Interesting! Can you run the same `UPDATE` view inside an SQLite shell like command line, CLI?